# How to separate words in table cells with a fixed width and vertically align the text?

Tags: tables, vertical-alignment, longtable, makecell

I need my table to fit in a A4 page so I fixed some of the columns. Now I run into various alignment an word separation problems. Like in the cell next to the ID A.7.2.2 I have no other idea how to separate the long word without \makecell. If I use \newline or \linebreak there is an empy line in between the words and if I simply let it be like that, the word is not separated at all and is written into the neighboring cell. Furthermore I want to fix the aligment. The ID column and the second column should be aligned in the middle of the cells and I don't understand why the last cell in the fifth column has a space between the line and the text while other cells don't.

Thx for help!

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[showframe=false, left=1.5cm, right=0.5cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{ctable}
\usepackage{boldline}
\usepackage{makecell}


\title{Erklärung zur Anwendbarkeit der ISO 27001}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\begin{longtable}{V{3}c|p{3.7cm}|c|p{4cm}|p{3.5cm}|cV{3}}
\specialrule{0.15em}{0em}{0em}   

ID & \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß \\ ISO/IEC 27001} & \thead[l]{Anwend- \\barkeit} & \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl \\  bzw. Ausschluss} & Maßnahmeziele & Umsetzung \\

\specialrule{0.15em}{0em}{0em}  
\endhead

A.7.1.1 & Sicherheitsüberprüfung & & & Interessierte Personen werden vor einer Beschäftigung nach relevanten Gesetzen einer Sicherheitsüberprüfung unterzogen. & \\
\hline
A.7.1.2 & Beschäftigungs- und Vertragsbedingungen & & & Die Verantwortlichkeiten für die Beschäftigten und der Organisation sind vertraglich festgelegt. & \\
\hline
\multicolumn{1}{V{3}l|}{A.7.2} & \multicolumn{5}{ c V{3}}{Während der Beschäftigung}\\
\hline
A.7.2.1 & Verantwortlichkeit der  Leitung & & & Die Leitung verlangt von den Beschäftigten die Umsetzung der Informationssicherheit nach den Richtlinien. & \\
\hline
A.7.2.2 & \makecell[l]{Informationssichheits- \\ bewusstsein,\\ -ausbildung \\ und -schulung} & & & Durch Schulungen, Aus- und Weiterbildungen werden bei den Beschäftigten  ein angemessenes Bewusstsein gefördert.&\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit**: Zarko helped me a lot, but when I try to manually break a line with \makecell I get a weird vertical alignment for the cell compared to other cells

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=0.5cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, xltabular}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}
\usepackage{boldline} 


\title{Erklärung zur Anwendbarkeit der ISO 27001}
\date{}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle


{
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{V{3} l | L | c | L | L | c V{3}}
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
ID  &   \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß\\ ISO/IEC 27001} 
        &   \thead[l]{Anwend-\\ barkeit} 
            &   \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl\\  bzw. Ausschluss} 
                &   \thead{Maßnahmeziele} 
                    &   \thead{Umsetzung}       \\
    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\endfirsthead
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
ID  &   \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß \\ ISO/IEC 27001}
        &   \thead[l]{Anwend- \\barkeit}
            &   \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl \\  bzw. Ausschluss}
                &   \thead{Maßnahmeziele}
                    &   \thead{Umsetzung}       \\

    \Xhline{0.8pt}
\endhead
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Fortsetzung auf der nächsten Seite}}
\endfoot
    \Xhline{1.2pt}
\endlastfoot
% table body

A.5.1.1 & Informationssicherheitsrichtlinien & ja & essentielle Richtlinien & Festlegung, Genehmigung und Herausgabe von Informationssicherheitsrichtlinien. &  \makecell[l]{Beschreibung in: \\ some.dat}\\

\end{xltabular}
}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Do you really need `longtable` (does table span more than one page) ?

Comment: yes, it will go over several pages like that, thus I need the table header on every page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With use of the `xltabular`, `ragged2e`, and `booktabs` packages, without vertical lines:

[image]

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=0.5cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, booktabs, makecell, xltabular}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}}X}

%\title{Erklärung zur Anwendbarkeit der ISO 27001}
%\date{}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

{
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{@{} l L c L L c @{}}
    \toprule
ID  &   \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß\\ ISO/IEC 27001} 
        &   \thead[l]{Anwend-\\ barkeit} 
            &   \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl\\  bzw. Ausschluss} 
                &   \thead{Maßnahmeziele} 
                    &   \thead{Umsetzung}       \\
    \midrule
\endfirsthead
    \toprule
ID  &   \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß \\ ISO/IEC 27001}
        &   \thead[l]{Anwend- \\barkeit}
            &   \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl \\  bzw. Ausschluss}
                &   \thead{Maßnahmeziele}
                    &   \thead{Umsetzung}       \\

    \midrule
\endhead
    \midrule[\heavyrulewidth]
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \bottomrule
\endlastfoot
% table body
A.7.1.1 & Sicherheitsüberprüfung & & & Interessierte Personen werden vor einer Beschäftigung nach relevanten Gesetzen einer Sicherheitsüberprüfung unterzogen.   & \\
    \addlinespace
A.7.1.2 & Beschäftigungs- und Vertragsbedingungen & & & Die Verantwortlichkeiten für die Beschäftigten und der Organisation sind vertraglich festgelegt.     & \\
    \midrule
A.7.2   & \multicolumn{5}{c}{Während der Beschäftigung}             \\
    \midrule
A.7.2.1 & Verantwortlichkeit der  Leitung & & & Die Leitung verlangt von den Beschäftigten die Umsetzung der Informationssicherheit nach den Richtlinien.          & \\
    \addlinespace    
A.7.2.2 & Informationssichheits -bewusstsein, -ausbildung und -schulung & & & Durch Schulungen, Aus- und Weiterbildungen werden bei den Beschäftigten  ein angemessenes Bewusstsein gefördert.  &   \\
\end{xltabular}
}

\end{document}
```

**Edit (2):**

- It is very difficult to help you since of lack of information and their change all the times, so here is second (and the last mine) correction of this edit.
- You not need to use `\makecell` package, better is used column type, which enable automatic break text in cells to necessary number of lines.

[image]

Corrected MWE is now:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[left=1.5cm, right=0.5cm, a4paper, twoside]{geometry}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\usepackage{array, makecell, xltabular}
    \renewcommand\theadfont{\small\bfseries}
    \renewcommand\theadgape{}
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\RaggedRight\hspace{0pt}\hsize=#1\hsize}X} % <---
\usepackage{boldline} % <---


%\title{Erklärung zur Anwendbarkeit der ISO 27001}
%\date{}

\begin{document}
%\maketitle

{
\setlength\tabcolsep{4pt}
\setcellgapes{3pt}
\makegapedcells
\begin{xltabular}{\linewidth}{V{3} l | L{1.1} | c | L{1.1} | L{1.1} | L{0.7} V{3}}
    \hlineB{3}
ID  &   \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß\\ ISO/IEC 27001} 
        &   \thead[l]{Anwend-\\ barkeit} 
            &   \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl\\  bzw. Ausschluss} 
                &   \thead{Maßnahmeziele} 
                    &   \thead{Umsetzung}       \\
    \hlineB{2}
\endfirsthead
    \hlineB{3}
ID  &   \thead[l]{Maßnahmen gemäß \\ ISO/IEC 27001}
        &   \thead[l]{Anwend- \\barkeit}
            &   \thead[l]{Grund für Auswahl \\  bzw. Ausschluss}
                &   \thead{Maßnahmeziele}
                    &   \thead{Umsetzung}       \\

    \hlineB{2}
\endhead
    \hlineB{3}
    \multicolumn{6}{r}{\footnotesize\textit{Continue on the next page}}
\endfoot
    \hlineB{3}
\endlastfoot
% table body
A.5.1.1     & Informationssicherheitsrichtlinien & ja & essentielle Richtlinien & Festlegung, Genehmigung und Herausgabe von Informationssicherheitsrichtlinien. &  Beschreibung in: some.dat \\
    \hline
A.7.1.1 & Sicherheitsüberprüfung & & & Interessierte Personen werden vor einer Beschäftigung nach relevanten Gesetzen einer Sicherheitsüberprüfung unterzogen.   & \\
    \hline
A.7.1.2 & Beschäftigungs- und Vertragsbedingungen & & & Die Verantwortlichkeiten für die Beschäftigten und der Organisation sind vertraglich festgelegt.     & \\
    \hline
A.7.2   & \multicolumn{5}{cV{3}}{Während der Beschäftigung}             \\
    \hline
A.7.2.1 & Verantwortlichkeit der  Leitung & & & Die Leitung verlangt von den Beschäftigten die Umsetzung der Informationssicherheit nach den Richtlinien.          & \\
    \hline
A.7.2.2 & Informationssichheits -bewusstsein, -aus\-bild\-ung und -schulung & & & Durch Schulungen, Aus- und Weiterbildungen werden bei den Beschäftigten  ein angemessenes Bewusstsein gefördert.  &   \\
\end{xltabular}
}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks, I prefer the solution with the lines. How can I realize the bold outer lines in your example? I used the V{3} from ctable package to do so in mine.

Comment: @Namal, see edited answer. Personally I prefer the first version of table. You may look wiert.me/2014/04/03/… (it is about table settings).

Comment: thanks for the link, it is very informative. But I have a lot of text and no numbers at all, a lot of multicolumns too, that is why I think that jailed cells would be better. Furthermore I have a question about the column width control. How do you do it? In case I need to make it wider or narrower.

Comment: @Namal, BTW `V{3}` is defined in the `boldline` package, not in `ctable` :-). See edited answer.

Comment: @Zako, unfortunately I ran again in the weird alignment problem, when I manually break the line: 
A.5.1.1 & Informationssicherheitsrichtlinien & ja & essentielle Richtlinien & Festlegung, Genehmigung und Herausgabe von Informationssicherheitsrichtlinien. &  \makecell[l]{Beschreibung in: \\ some.dat}\\
Other than that I don't know how to begin a new line since \newline or \linebreak does not work.

Comment: @Namal, why you do this? Your demands are unclear.

Comment: sorry for that, I have edited my question.

Comment: @Nathal, see edited answer. If you will still have problem with this table, please ask new question. BTW, as far as I see, so far you not accept any of received answer. Why? Did no one deserve to be accepted (by clicking on check mark at top left side of answer)? Since you not doing this, you send message to audience, that your question so far haven't be solved. Is this true?